# How can I get the windows installation in a virtualbox in ubuntu host to have full resolution as the original monitor?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've installed virtualbox with the following command

```
$ apt install virtualbox
```

Then I installed Windows 7 in the virtualbox. But I notice that even though there are very high resolution options in the personalization section, none of them are what my native resolution is, which is `1366x768`. I can make the virtualbox window with `RCtrl-F` but that's not what this question is about. I want to have the resolution of the virtualbox the same as my native resolution.

There must be a more appropriate way to use the virtualbox. Many of the people use virtualbox to test cross-platform applications and I would think they have a workable virtualbox setup.

> How do I force the Windows 7 installation in a virtualbox to adopt the native resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install virtualbox guest addition in the guest OS. In your case, you have Ubuntu as the main/host OS and Windows as the guest OS, so you need to install the guest additions in the Windows OS.

You can do that with following the prompts and pop-ups after clicking on `Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image`